# how to create and move between screens in a bash.sh script

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I have a command that i would like to run in different screens numerous times.
it there a way to do it in a bash script?
i would like to do the following 
create a screen > get into screen > run command > detached the screen
thank you!

Comment: Are you talking about GNU Screen?

Comment: yes, i know how to do it manually screen -S and Ctrl A D. but is there a way to automate it ?

Comment: `screen detach` is equivalent to `Ctl-a d`

Comment: `screen pow_detach` is equivalent to `Ctl-a D`

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Power-Detach

Comment: and what is equivalent to screen -S name?

Comment: What do you mean? That's the command.

Comment: Put your code in the question, with readable formatting

Comment: ok got it! it should to be ^a ^d in the code.

Comment: You don't put the control sequences in the script, you put the corresponding `screen` commands.